# Stopping an Android Activity, use noHistory="true"

Tags: android

I had read about this thread around the Internet but I haven't found the solution. The solutions like :noHistory="true" in the Manifest file. What I wanted is that after the user clicks the save button in AddNewItem class, which will redirect the user into the MainActivity class, when the user clicks the back button, it will go back to the mainMenu, no going back at every step I have made.

This is my manifest file

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.shoppingapp.AddNewItems"
            android:label="" 
             android:noHistory="true">

        </activity>
```

This is my mai activity>

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // The Intent is used to issue that an operation should
    // be performed

    Intent intent;
    TextView itemId;

    // The object that allows me to manipulate the database

    ShoppingDB shopdatabase = new ShoppingDB(this);

    // Called when the Activity is first called

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get saved data if there is any

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Designate that edit_contact.xml is the interface used
        // is activity_main.xml

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Gets all the data from the database and stores it
        // in an ArrayList

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList =  shopdatabase.getAllItems();

        // Check to make sure there are contacts to display

        if(contactList.size()!=0) {

            // Get the ListView and assign an event handler to it

            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                    // When an item is clicked get the TextView
                    // with a matching checkId

                    itemId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemId);

                    // Convert that itemId into a String

                    String itemIdValue = itemId.getText().toString();   

                    // Signals an intention to do something
                    // getApplication() returns the application that owns
                    // this activity

                    Intent  theIndent = new Intent(getApplication(),EditItemList.class);

                    // Put additional data in for EditContact to use

                    theIndent.putExtra("itemId", itemIdValue); 

                    // Calls for EditContact

                    startActivity(theIndent); 

                                    }
            }); 

            // A list adapter is used bridge between a ListView and
            // the ListViews data

            // The SimpleAdapter connects the data in an ArrayList
            // to the XML file

            // First we pass in a Context to provide information needed
            // about the application
            // The ArrayList of data is next followed by the xml resource
            // Then we have the names of the data in String format and
            // their specific resource ids

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,contactList, R.layout.item_list_entry, new String[] { "itemId","textAmount", "textItem"}, new int[] {R.id.itemId, R.id.textAmount, R.id.textItem});

            // setListAdapter provides the Cursor for the ListView
            // The Cursor provides access to the database data

            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }

    }


    public void callStartApp(View view){

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), StartingApp.class);

        startActivity(startIntent);

    }

    // When showAddContact is called with a click the Activity 
    // NewContact is called

    public void showAddItem(View view) {
        Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNewItems.class);
        startActivity(theIntent);
    }


}
```

and this is my AddNewItem class

```
public class AddNewItems extends Activity {

    // The EditText objects

        EditText textItem;
        EditText textAmount;
        EditText textPrice;
        EditText textPlace;

        ShoppingDB shopdatabase = new ShoppingDB(this);


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get saved data if there is any

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Designate that add_new_item.xml is the interface used

    setContentView(R.layout.add_item);

    // Initialize the EditText objects

    textItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textItem);
    textAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
    textPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
    textPlace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPlace);


}
public void addNewItems(View view) {

    // Will hold the HashMap of values 

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new  HashMap<String, String>();

    // Get the values from the EditText boxes

    queryValuesMap.put("textItem", textItem.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("textAmount", textAmount.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("textPrice", textPrice.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("textPlace", textPlace.getText().toString());


    // Call for the HashMap to be added to the database

    shopdatabase.insertItem(queryValuesMap);

    // Call for MainActivity to execute

    this.callMainActivity(view);
}
public void callMainActivity(View view) {
    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(theIntent);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its redirect to mainactivty class-

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MAinActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
```

For mainMenu-

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, abcActivity.class);
    finish();
```

Here i write abcActivity for your mainmenuActivity. Write your menuActivity calss name at place of abcActivity.

Comment: @user2760701 mine pleasure.

Comment: @user2760701 if this answer works please like it so that its help other also.